# How to update parent dependency after i update children denpendency using maven

Tags: java, maven

I use IDEA,My springboot app contains multiple modules like that:

```
parent
 -web
 -service
 -dao
```

There is a jar dependency `common:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT` in `service` module defined in pom.xml, I updated its version to `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT`, after that i do maven reimport and run `mvn clean install -U` but these two versions still in dependencies list, and in dependency tree, two jar in the dependencies, also when i run the app, it throw `NoClassDefFoundError` error which i added in 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT

This is my maven dependenct tree:

```
service:jar
+- dao:jar
\- common:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT

web:jar
+- service:jar
  +- dao:jar
  \- common:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
\- others:jar
```

service pom dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com</groupId>
   <artifactId>common</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

How can i update the dependency?

Comment: You should _probably_ be using Maven `<properties>` _and_ `<dependencyManagement>`, both located in the `parent` module.

Comment: @chrylis, add pom dependency, common version is defined in service pom, also, i checked `<properties>` and `<dependencyManagement>`, no common version defined.

Will check other dependencies's config as will.

Comment: are you by any chance setting version for service module and web is referring to old version of service module in its pom?

Comment: @Haroon @chrylis, checked again, found there is `<parent>` in parent pom.xml, under this pom, common version is `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT`, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Haroon @chrylis said, i checked the parent `pom.xml` and found `<parent>` configured in this pom.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>insight.plat</groupId>
        <artifactId>insight-bom-base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

in pom `insight-bom-base`, `common 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` is configured, so web module depend this version not version `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`.

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependencyManagement>
```

As maven doc [Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) shows,

```
Dependency management - this allows project authors to directly specify the 
versions of artifacts to be used when they are encountered in transitive 
dependencies or in dependencies where no version has been specified. 
In the example in the preceding section a dependency was directly added to A even though 
it is not directly used by A. 
Instead, A can include D as a dependency in its dependencyManagement section and directly 
control which version of D is used when, or if, it is ever referenced.
```

The parent `dependencyManagement` has higher priority than Transitive Dependencies, so in service module, it use `common 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Solution is update common version in parent pom file